# Getting Assertion Error but code output matches assert

Tags: python, assertion

My problem is that when i run my code with the input 'word1 word2 word3 word2' (for example) it works as intended, meaning it removes a word if it finds a duplicate of that word in the string.

I have no clue why i get assertion error why i try to run:

```
set1 = StringSet('word1 word2 word3 word2')
assert str(set1) == 'word1 word2 word3'

output:

assert str(set1) == 'word1 word2 word3'
AssertionError
```

if i remove the assert and print set1 the code works.

```
'word1 word2 word3'
```

Thanks in regards.

My code:

```
class StringSet:


    def __init__(self, a_string=""):
        self.a_string = a_string
        self.__words = []
        for word in a_string.split(" "):
            if word not in self.__words:
                self.__words.append(word)
              
    def __str__(self):
        s = ""
        for word in self.__words:
            s+= f"{word}"
            s+=" "   
        return "{}".format(s)
        
    def size(self):
        counter = 0
        for word in self.__words:
            counter += 1
        return f"{counter}"


    def __add__(self, other):
        s = ""
        new_string = self.a_string + " " + other.a_string
        new_set = StringSet(new_string)
        return new_set

    def make_list(self):
        pass

    def query(self, a_string=""):
        new_string = StringSet(a_string)
        return new_string

    def at(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Sets are unordered.  Are you sure the order matches?  The safest thing would be to do a set comparison, rather than turning the set into a string and then crossing your fingers in the hope that the element orders match.  If you really want to a canonical string, then you need to (1) convert the set to a list (2) sort the list (3) convert the list to a string.  But don't do that.  Just compare the sets directly.  E.g. do `set1 == {'word1', 'word2', 'word3'}`.  That is guaranteed to work.

Comment: `StringSet.__str__()` is adding a trailing space to non-empty sets, so it's not equal to a string lacking that space.

Comment: @jasonharper That's a good point, but the bigger problem is that two sets with identical elements do not necessarily produce those elements in the same order when iterating over them, so the entire strategy of converting to strings and then comparing strings will be buggy unless the sets are first converted to lists, then those lists are sorted.  It's very easy to create examples of two equivalent lists that print differently.  Direct set comparison makes much more sense.